# Handeling an async call before transitioning to a new route

Tags: ember.js

I want to get the users Geolocation. Once I get the coordinates, I want to load Records based on that Geolocation. If there is more than 1 result, show an index page,

```
LHW.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 11
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api'

LHW.Company = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  address: DS.attr 'string'
  city: DS.attr 'string'

LHW.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, route) ->
    # get Geolocation
    _route = @
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ((location) ->
      #success
      _route.geoLocation(location)
     ), (error) ->
      #error
      switch(error.code)
        when error.PERMISSION_DENIED then console.log "User denied the request for Geolocation."
        when error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE then console.log "Location information is unavailable."
        when error.TIMEOUT then console.log "The request to get user location timed out."
        when error.UNKNOWN_ERROR then console.log "An unknown error occurred."

  geoLocation: (location) ->
    _route = @
    @get('store').findQuery('company',{longitude: location.coords.longitude, latitude: location.coords.latitude}).then ((data) =>
      _route.controllerFor('companies').set('content', data)
      if data.get('length') > 1
        _route.transitionTo('companies');

    ), (error) ->
      console.log "error"

LHW.CompaniesRoute = Ember.Route.extend()

LHW.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  beforeModel: ->
    console.log 'before'
```

So this is what I got now. But this has a few problems

1. If you go to /companies instead of / It skips the geolocation
   check. But if I move the geolocation to the companies route, then
   what is the page the users sees while geolocation is getting
   fetched?
2. Creating a switch and checking the length in a route,
   feels a bit dirty, imo the Companyroute should respond to that

So this is mostly a flow issue I can't wrap my head around and the async geolocation isn't making things easier...

Comment: I'm in exactly the same boat right now. Did you find an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Same sort of problem I am facing! Any luck or direction??